# WCF serialization - convert to different type on the fly?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF service interface that looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://somenamespace", SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface IRuntimeService
{

    [OperationContract]
    ISupporterProperties CreateOrModifySupporter(Guid id);

}
```

And the implementation (both on the client and the server) looks like this (it is hosted and connected to programmatically):

```
public IOwnerProperties CreateOrModifyOwner(Guid id)
{

    //get an owner ...

    //the owner is of type Owner which implements IOwnerProperties.
    return theOwner;

}
```

However, the issue is here that WCF will try to serialize or deserialize this as an `Owner` since that is the actual type being returned, but I would like it to send it over as a `OwnerDataContract` which also happens to implement `IOwnerProperties`.

In other words, I want to return an `Owner`, but make it serialize/deserialize it as a `OwnerDataContract`.

I am aware that I can create a wrapper class for the client's interface. However, I would like to have as much shared code as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfect job for [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). If `Owner` and `OwnerDataContract` have the same properties and fields the setup is as simple as

```
static void Main()
{
    //Do this once at program startup
    Mapper.CreateMap<Owner, OwnerDataContract>();

    //Run the rest of your program.
}
```

If you need to remap some properties due to flattening or renaming there will be more setup work, see [the wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/_pages) for more info.

To use the mapping it is as simple as

```
public IOwnerProperties CreateOrModifyOwner(Guid id)
{

    //get an owner ...

    //Mapper.Map retuns a object of type OwnerDataContract
    return Mapper.Map<OwnerDataContract>(theOwner);
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. Is there a way of doing it without using third party tools?

Comment: Yea but that would be making a "wapper class" which you said you did not want to do. Automapper dynamically makes those wrappers via `Mapper.CreateMap`